# Unable to get keycode of "Fn" in custom layout

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 22.04, compose-key

I have a Logitech K380, and I decided to change its layout to follow the "MacOS French" layout.

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`

So far so good.

Now, in this specific keyboard layout, there are a few characters that are only shown using the `Fn` key. Such as: `~` (by pressing: `Fn + N`) or `|` (by pressing: `ctrl + shift + L`).

1. using `xev` - I cannot find the keycode for the Fn key (After a bit of reading - I came to understand that the Fn key is not defined at the Software level - so how would one make use of it ?)
2. Without the keycode - how could I work around it by making it a compose key?
3. If it's ultimately unusable, would there be a way to push it all the way to the left of the keyboard such as the MacOS keyboard layout?